# Finding average of a certain number is not working

Tags: python

```
print("Please think of a secret number between 0 and 100")
low = 0
high = 100
average = low + high / 2

print("Is your number " + str(average) + "?")
guess = input ("If not enter 'h' if it is too high, 'l' if it is too low, 'c' if it was correct\n")
if guess == "l":
    low = average
    print("Is your number " + str(low + high/2) + "?")
```

I haven't finished the program but when printing the program and inputting "l", it doesn't print out 75 like I would like it to.

Comment: `low + high / 2` is not the same as `(low + high)/2` (unless `low` is zero)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is math : `low+high/2` is different of `(low+high)/2`, just compute again the `average` with the good formula

```
print("Please think of a secret number between 0 and 100")
low = 0
high = 100
average = (low + high) / 2

print("Is your number " + str(average) + "?")
guess = input("If not enter 'h' if it is too high, 'l' if it is too low, 'c' if it was correct\n")
if guess == "l":
    low = average
    average = (low + high) / 2
    print("Is your number " + str(average) + "?")
```

Comment: Completely forget about my order of operations thank you very much!

Comment: @t0rror so you accept the answer of the man you answered 5min after me, after thanking me, hum nice move

Answer (score 0):

Since Python does follow the order of operations you should probably try changing, str(low + high/2) to str((low + high) / 2)